# Data sequence number of the packet and Data sequence number of the data expected in return

Tags: tcp

I need to know what is the different between the Data sequence number of the packet and Data sequence number of the data expected in return for the TCP packets.

What is the different between them?

Is it true if i subtract them ,the result will be the packet size ?

BR
Rayan

Answer (score 0):

TCP runs sequence numbers in both directions independently.

> Is it true if i subtract them ,the result will be the packet size ?

No.